# How do I grayscale images programmatically?

Tags: react-native

Most of the libraries out there are about filtering image components. All I really want is a library or something which makes it possible to grayscale images programmatically. It might work like, when you provide it with an image path, the library would asynchronously spit out the path of the grayscaled image.

Comment: Maybe you do not need a library. Add a [class](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-styling.html) to your component and style it with CSS to greyscale the image, see [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_filter.php).

Comment: I need to provide an ML model with a grayscaled image via its path.